# Catching derived exception by copy construction

Tags: c++11, exception

Assume I'm writing a shared library and trying to make sure that the interface functions never throw. I have my own exception type that I throw, but since I'm using STL a lot I need to avoid any exceptions from there too. So, if I am lazy and don't want to have an additional `catch(const std::exception&) {}` block in each interface function, is it possible to derive my exception type from `std::exception` so that when an `std::exception` is thrown a constructor of my exception type is invoked with the original exception and then I could have a single catch handler with my exception type.

Ideally I would like something similar to this snippet (which obviously doesn't work), but maybe there are other techniques which I'm not seeing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class derived_exception : public std::exception
{
public:
    derived_exception(const std::exception& exception)
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        throw std::exception("test");
    }
    catch (const derived_exception& exception)
    {
        std::cout << exception.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this won't work. It's not type-safe. You might want to think about approaching this differently - part of the point of throwing multiple types of errors is to give you the control to catch exceptions of different types to react to different sorts of errors.

Comment: @templatetypedef well I can just copy the `std::exception` blocks everywhere:D I was just wondering if I can satisfy my lazyness:D

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: I think `catch (...)` is the only way to do what you are saying...  caveat emptor